# Safely checking if a variable is nil in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, thread-safety

I have an Objective-C class with the following property:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *myString;
```

The value that's assigned to myString comes from a remote server. I download the remote contents in another thread using `performSelectorInBackground`. Once the data has been downloaded I pass it to a selector on the main thread using `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:`. In this selector I assign the data to myString.

**How can I safely check if myString is nil in a selector on the main thread?**

So I'd like to just ask `if (myString)` in some selector on the main thread. However I'm unsure about the threading considerations. Perhaps this is a case where the property should be atomic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the main thread is the only thread in the system that accesses `myString`, then the property access is effectively single-threaded, and you do not need `atomic`. If the main thread is the only one doing the writing, but other threads also read `myString`, declaring the property `atomic` is a good thing to do. In case of multi-threaded access, make sure that you use immutable `NSString` rather than the `NSMutableString`, because even making your property `atomic` is not going to protect a mutable string from returning incorrect results on reads running concurrently with writes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are both reading and writing the value of that property on the main thread, then there's no concurrency, and you don't need to take any special precautions.

Answer (score 1):

Once you're in the method triggered by `performSelectorOnMainThread:`, your threading considerations are over. If you don't have any accesses to `myString` except from the main thread, then nothing can race with you, and the obvious `if (myString)` will work.

If you're using [`NSURLConnection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE), though, you are probably overcomplicating it. You can asynchronously perform a network request without involving threads at all.

Comment: I'm not using `NSURLConnection` explicitly. Just `performSelectorInBackground` and `performSelectorOnMainThread`.

Comment: @SundayMonday Right, you said that. But multithreading is kind of heavyweight for simply performing a download in the background. I'm trying to suggest alternatives.

Comment: Indeed. Would the alternatives involve blocks somehow?

Comment: Not necessarily. `NSURLConnection` uses delegates (and 10.7 added a block-based method).